# How to automate module reloading when unit testing with Erlang?

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, erlang

I'm using Emacs and trying to get my unit testing work flow as automated as possible. I have it set up so it is working but I have to manually compile my module under test or the module containing the tests before the Erlang Shell recognizes my changes.

I have two files `mymodule.erl` and `mymodule_tests.erl`. What I would like to be able to do is:

1. Add test case to mymodule_tests
2. Save mymodule_tests
3. Switch to the Erlang Shell
4. Run tests with one line, like `eunit:test(mymodule)` or `mymodule_tests:test()`
5. Have Erlang reload mymodule and mymodule_tests before actually performing the tests

I have tried writing my own test method but it doesn't work.

```
-module (mytests).
-export([test/0]).

-import(mymodule).
-import(mymodule_tests).
-import(code).

test() ->
    code:purge(mymodule),
    code:delete(mymodule),
    code:load_file(mymodule),
    code:purge(mymodule_tests),
    code:delete(mymodule_tests),
    code:load_file(mymodule_tests),
    mymodule_tests:test().
```

I have also tried by putting `-compile(mymodule).` into mymodule_tests to see if I could get mymodule to automatically reload when updating mymodule_tests but to no avail.

I have also googled quite a bit but can't find any relevant information. As I'm new to Erlang I'm thinking that I'm either searching for the wrong terms, e.g. `erlang reload module`, or that you are not supposed to be able reload other modules when compile another module.

Comment: You could maybe just write a custom function in your .erlang file that does basicalle `Test = fun(Atom) -> S = atom_to_list(A), c(A), c(S++"_tests"), eunit:test(A) end`, which you could call as `Test(module)`, automatically compiling and reloading everything before each test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the [Erlang make](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html#all-1) can help you.

```
make:all([load]).
```

Reading from the doc:

> This function first looks in the
>   current working directory for a file
>   named Emakefile (see below) specifying
>   the set of modules to compile and the
>   compile options to use. If no such
>   file is found, the set of modules to
>   compile defaults to all modules in the
>   current working directory.

And regarding the "load" option:

> Load mode. Loads all recompiled
>   modules.

There's also a `make:files/1,2` which allows you to specify the list of modules to check.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `l(mymodule).` to reload the module after it's been compiled?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. There is no problem if I just do the normal `C-c C-k` for `mymodule` and then `mymodule_tests`. I trying to come up with a way for either Erlang or Emacs to compile the modules automatically before running the tests.